# Extending functionality of org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet

Tags: java, inheritance, spring, factory-method, static

I would like to be able to set token values (defaultFieldSet.tokens) and names (defaultFieldSet.names) on `org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet` using a `java.util.Properties` object. Specifically, the keys of the Properties object will serve as the names and the corresponding Properties values will serve as the tokens. Here's the code that I have to do this:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;

/**
 * <code>PropertiesFieldSetFactory</code> is a factory to create
 * a {@link FieldSet} from a {@link Properties} object.
*/
public class PropertiesFieldSetFactory {

    /**
     * Creates a {@link FieldSet} by setting its token values equal to the {@link Properties} values
     * and its token names equal to the {@link Properties} keys. 
     * Note: Passing a null argument to this method will cause a {@link NullPointerException} 
     * to be thrown.
     * 
     * @param properties used to populate the {@link FieldSet}
     * @return {@link FieldSet} that has token values and names from the passed in {@link Properties} object
     */
    public static FieldSet create(Properties properties) {
        final Set<String> tokenNamesSet = properties.stringPropertyNames();
        final int numberOfTokens = tokenNamesSet.size(); 
        final String[] tokenNames = tokenNamesSet.toArray(new String[numberOfTokens]);
        final String[] tokenValues = new String[numberOfTokens];
        for (int tokenPosition = 0; tokenPosition < numberOfTokens; tokenPosition++) {
            String tokenName = tokenNames[tokenPosition];
            tokenValues[tokenPosition] = properties.getProperty(tokenName);
        }
        return new DefaultFieldSet(tokenValues, tokenNames);
    }

}
```

My concern with this approach is in regards to unit testing. For example, I have the following method (in another class) that needs to be unit tested:

```
public class CarFieldSetMapper extends BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Car> {

    @Override
    public Car mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {        
        Properties fieldProperties = fieldSet.getProperties();

        fieldProperties.put("modelDescription", fieldProperties.get("model"));

        removeDummyIndicator(fieldSet, fieldProperties);

        // build field from properties derived / transformed from the original field set
        FieldSet domainObjectFieldSet = PropertiesFieldSetFactory.create(fieldProperties);

        return super.mapFieldSet(domainObjectFieldSet);
    }

    private void removeDummyIndicator(FieldSet fieldSet, Properties fieldProperties) {
        // dummyIndicator is not a field of any domain object
        final String dummyIndicatorTokenName = "dummyIndicator";
        final String isDummyIndicator = fieldSet.readString(dummyIndicatorTokenName);
        if (isDummyIndicator.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            fieldProperties.put("model", "");
        }
        fieldProperties.remove(dummyIndicatorTokenName);
    }
}
```

I do not know of a great way to prevent `PropertiesFieldSetFactory.create()` from being called when running the unit test ala http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/. Also, I'm really trying to extend the `DefaultFieldSet` functionality so I question using a factory. Note: On the other hand, Joshua Bloch seems to promote use of static factory methods in Effective Java (Chapter 2: Item 1).

Should I change `PropertiesFieldSetFactory` to `PropertiesFieldSet` extending `DefaultFieldSet`? If so, how can I set the `FieldSet` `tokens` and `names`. Both fields are private on the `DefaultFieldSet` without any way to set the values other than during construction.

**Edit:** Added code for removeDummyIndicator and correction of line `fieldProperties.put("model", fieldProperties.get("model"));` to `fieldProperties.put("modelDescription", fieldProperties.get("model"));`

Comment: Now you can +1 ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real issue here is that you do not need a `PropertiesFieldSetFactory`. Take a look at how you currently use it:

```
@Override
public Car mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {        
    Properties fieldProperties = fieldSet.getProperties();

    fieldProperties.put("modelDescription", fieldProperties.get("model"));

    removeDummyIndicator(fieldSet, fieldProperties);

    // build field from properties derived / transformed from the original field set
    FieldSet domainObjectFieldSet = PropertiesFieldSetFactory.create(fieldProperties);

    return super.mapFieldSet(domainObjectFieldSet);
}
```

This code is taking as input the `FieldSet` that was tokenized by the `LineTokenizer` you are using. It adds car-specific values to the `Properties` of that `FieldSet`, removes a value in case a dummy parameter is set, and reconstructs a `FieldSet` back from those properties. Those hoops are needed because `FieldSet` is immutable.

But look at this again: you don't need to fiddle with the `FieldSet`, only to have everything set-up automagically by the `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`. Store the result of `super.mapFieldSet` (invoked with the `fieldSet` given to the mapper) to a local `car` and do the necessary logic on that car:

```
public class CarFieldSetMapper extends BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Car> {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setStrict(false); // <-- ignore the non-existant "dummyIndicator"
        setTargetType(Car.class);
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    @Override
    public Car mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {        
        Car car = super.mapFieldSet(fieldSet);
        car.setModelDescription(car.getModel());
        if (fieldSet.readString("dummyIndicator").equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            car.setModel(null);
        }
        return car;
    }

}
```

The Spring Batch approach to reading a file is:

- Take a `LineMapper` which is supposed to read a line and map it into your domain objects.
- This mapper tokenizes the line into a `FieldSet` with a `LineTokenizer` and maps this `FieldSet` into your domain object with a `FieldSetMapper`. As you can see, it is the tokenizer role to make a `FieldSet` out of the line, which is then used by the mapper to create the final domain object.
- By default, the line tokenizer creates `FieldSet` instances using a `FieldSetFactory`. It gets the names you configured and the values come from the parsed line.

So once the `FieldSet` has been constructed by the `LineTokenizer`, it should not be re-created: it contains the data as specified in the line that was read. This data is then transformed into your domain object; hence the only place to implement domain-specific logic is in the mapper, directly with the instance to be returned, and not in the `FieldSet`.

Comment: I've included the missing method for removeDummyIndicator and correction to the `fieldProperties.put("model", fieldProperties.get("model"));` line. (Sorry about that.)

Comment: @James I edited with a possible approach. The idea is still the same: create the fieldset from the linetokenizer only.

Comment: That's great. I would give +1 but I'm new to Code Review and don't have the rep yet. The idea to move the `Properties` put / remove work from a `FieldSetMapper` to a `LineTokenizer` is perfect and makes a lot of sense. But what about the code of the `PropertiesFieldSetFactory`? Its code is fairly generic in nature (independent of `LineTokenizer`) and I will have other code that will need to convert `Properties` to token values and names. I feel like that we just shifted that problem to another class (i.e. from `CarFieldSetMapper` to `FieldSetPropertiesLineTokenizer`).